# css to create zero-width non-space strings

Tags: css

Dear css experts:  In my field, it is common to denote statistical significance with *'s on the numbers.  I know I could put all stars in their own td field and then use css so that numbers are aligned, but I was wondering if this can be done in native css.  the intent is to have an ability to realign numbers:

```
<html>

<head> <style type="text/css"> td { text-align:right; } </style> </head>

<body>

<table>

<tr> <th>c</th> </tr>
<tr> <td>1</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>11</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>111</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>1111</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>11<sup style="text-width:0pt">**</sup></td> </tr>

</table>

</body>
```

possible?

Comment: I'm sorry, just to clarify, you would like to be able to align the stars wherever you would like, while the numbers stay in normal alignment?  Is it possible to have something like 111**111?  or are the stars always at the end of the number? Sincerely, !=mathman

Comment: Ivo, Check this fiddle out and let me know if this is what you were talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/umLtH/1/

Comment: thanks everyone.  I marked one of the answer as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible, and it’s a novel idea (at least new to me). The idea is apparently to have a column with numbers, aligned to their last digit, but with one or more characters (here, asterisks) to the right of some numbers. Wrapping those characters to an element, setting the element’s width to zero, and letting the content overflow (`overflow: visible`, the default) does the job. However, the width needs to be set using the `width` property, which has no effect on inline (text-level) elements, and `sup` is inline by default, so this needs to be fixed by making it an inline block (which *is* affected by the `width` property):

```
<style>
td { text-align:right; }
.after { display: inline-block; width: 0; }
</style>
...
<tr> <td>11<sup class=after>**</sup></td> </tr>
```

I have used the same markup as in the question. However, the `sup` element has several technical problems (e.g., it may cause line misalignment), so I would use `span` instead. You can style it in superscript style if desired. But e.g. Chicago Manual of Style, clause 3.78, uses simple asterisk “*” characters in text in this context, with no attempt at raised position or reduced font size. The point is that in any many commonly used fonts, the asterisk itself is, by typographic design, superscript-like: above the baseline and relatively small.

Here’s a screenshot of a test that uses this technique, first with `sup`, then, on the last row, with `span`. The font is Cambria.

[image]

Comment: thanks.  this is a complete form of the soln to my problem.  (I think the others had it, too, but the inline-block had to help me, too.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add '*' via css. You can do this:

```
td:after {
    content: '*';
    font-size: .8em;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mg425/1/)**